# How does OpenPGP handles situation when signatures on one OpenPGP key contradict each other?

Tags: pgp

For example, I was on a key signing party. After a party, one person signed my key with full trust and sent this signature to me by email. Then that person changed their mind and signed my key with marginal trust and uploaded that signature to a key server by themselves.
I have uploaded first signature with full trust to the key server after the person uploaded the second signature.
How these signatures will be combined on my OpenPGP key?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to Software model and not specifically to crypto.

Comment: IMHO the latest update is the one that is dominant.

Comment: How does OpenPGP decides which updates is the latest? For example, when person was making the second signature they set the time on their computer to yesterday.

Comment: BTW, I am ok to move the question to security StackExchange, if that is the better place for it.

Comment: I disagree that this needs to be closed. It should be answerable on the basis of how OpenPGP and its web of trust are defined.